# Update $scope doesn't affect the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update the $scope.loading from within the promise callback. I tried using $scope.$apply but I can't get it to work.

loading is a variable used in my view in order to show a loading bar if the data is not yet loaded, else show the data.

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('ecommerce')
    .controller('ProductsCtrl', function ($scope, ProductsService) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.error = false;
        ProductsService.getProducts().then(function (data) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.products = data;
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.products = null;
        });
});
```

This is my view :

```
<div ng-show="{{loading}}">Loading... please </div>
<div ng-hide="{{loading}}">
```

But i keep seeing the loading message, even when data is successfully loaded.

Comment: {{}} is when you want to display the value of something on the UI, {} is normally when you want to use the value in an expression or group of expressions. No {}'s when you want the value expressed by itself in ng-hide, ng-show and a handful of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `{{` and `}}`. Your `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives should look like this:

```
<div ng-show="loading">Loading... please </div>
<div ng-hide="loading">
```

See the docs for [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).

Answer (score 2):

Just put without experession `{{}}`.  According to the [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) documentation

```
<div ng-show="loading">Loading... please </div>
<div ng-hide="loading">
```

Here is the **[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/2jmxLo1f/)**